# How to connect Cisco 2911 into internet through the ISP's router?

Tags: networking, router

I recently got almost brand new Cisco 2911 router and Cisco 2960 switch for free from school. I've been configuring both a little bit in school so I can handle the basic stuff. I currently live in an older apartment where a coaxial cable comes into ISP's provided router. The router also happens to be a Cisco device (Cisco EPC3825). This router is wireless with four ethernet ports. Now, 2911 does not have a coaxial input so I have to put ISP's router before Cisco 2911 in my setup. This setup will be a temporary one and I am just testing how things work out. I am moving sooner to a newer apartment where there will be ethernet ports in the walls so I can move my ISP's router behind 2911.

I know my public IP address and ISP's provided gateway and DNS-servers. Currently ISP's router's LAN IP is 192.168.1.1. I connected from first ethernet port of the ISP's router into 2911's GigabitEthernet0/0 port. I gave an IP address of 192.168.1.2 to the 2911's 0/0 port. From GigabitEthernet0/1 goes ethernet cable into my 2960 switch and from there on it goes to my desktop machine and server machine. In the future I connect the ISP's router into the 2960. Currently I haven't made any changes into ISP's router's settings. They are pretty much factory defaults.

The network I have given to my LAN devices behind 2911 is 172.17.1.0/24. The 2911's 0/1 port has IP address of 172.17.1.1. The 2960 switch has IP address of 172.17.1.2. I installed a DHCP server on the 2911 router and when I connect my laptop into the switch it gives me an IP address from 172.17.1.10-172.17.1.250 area. Now I can ping from laptop the 2960 switch, 2911 router's both ports and the ISP's router. But then I cannot ping google's public DNS (8.8.8.8) nor ISP's provided gateway for example. I have desktop computer plugged straight into ISP's router, and internet works very well from there. Also if I connect my laptop via wireless into the ISP's router, internet works very well. But from either setup (desktop into ISP router or laptop via wireless into ISP router) I can only ping Cisco 2911's 0/0 port but not behind that. From the 2911 itself I cannot ping to either laptop nor desktop machine even when they have their firewalls off.

Here is the config of the 2911 router:

```
Current configuration : 1528 bytes
!
version 15.4
service timestamps debug datetime msec
service timestamps log datetime msec
service password-encryption
!
hostname Router
!
boot-start-marker
boot-end-marker
!
!
!
no aaa new-model
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
ip dhcp excluded-address 172.17.1.1 172.17.1.10
!
ip dhcp pool LAN_POOL
 network 172.17.1.0 255.255.255.0
 default-router 172.17.1.1
 dns-server 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4
 lease 7
!
!
!
ip cef
no ipv6 cef
multilink bundle-name authenticated
!
!
cts logging verbose
!
!
!
!
!
redundancy
!
!
!
!
!
!
interface Embedded-Service-Engine0/0
 no ip address
 shutdown
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/0
 ip address 192.168.1.2 255.255.255.0
 ip nat outside
 ip virtual-reassembly in
 duplex auto
 speed auto
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/1
 ip address 172.17.1.1 255.255.255.0
 ip nat inside
 ip virtual-reassembly in
 duplex auto
 speed auto
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/2
 no ip address
 shutdown
 duplex auto
 speed auto
!
ip forward-protocol nd
!
no ip http server
no ip http secure-server
!
ip nat inside source list 23 interface GigabitEthernet0/0 overload
ip route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 GigabitEthernet0/0
!
!
!
access-list 23 permit 172.17.1.0 0.0.0.25
!
control-plane
!
!
!
line con 0
 password 7 091D1C5A4A11141E
 login
line aux 0
line 2
 no activation-character
 no exec
 transport preferred none
 transport output pad telnet rlogin lapb-ta mop udptn v120 ssh
 stopbits 1
line vty 0 4
 password 7 0257560858120C2D
 login
 transport input none
!
scheduler allocate 20000 1000
!
end
```

As you can see from the configs I have tried to add static routing and playing with the NAT, neither one giving any results. What I am trying to achieve here is to connect to internet behind 2911 router, and to connect from internet to my server machine behind 2911 router. The solution may be simple but I just can't see it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I posted this to Cisco's support forums as well and there is the solution too.
https://supportforums.cisco.com/discussion/12501486/connecting-cisco-2911-internet-through-isps-router

Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1):

Please correct me if I am wrong about your current situation.

As I understand by looking at your question, you are using a cable modem and this is currently configured to connect to Internet using PPPoE. So, your ISP modem has username and password typed in the modem. You would not need to use two different subnet in this scenario unless you really want for some reasons but this is not a common setup in a business environment.

I would suggest that you put the Cisco EPC3825 in bridge mode so it does forward all traffic to your Cisco 2911. Let your powerful 2911 handle everything. You will need to configure your 2911 to request PPPoE connection to your ISP. To configure PPPoE on your router, you will need to add Dialer interface. If you are not familiar with the setup, check out this page for more information.
http://www.dslreports.com/faq/8199